# separated and dense in locally compact is discrete?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, compactness

It is true that if $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ $\delta$-separated and $\epsilon$-dense in $\mathbb{R}$ then $A$ is discrete? (This because of $\mathbb{R}$ is locally compact?

I ask this since $\mathbb{Z}$ is 1-separated and 1-dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and is discrete

Comment: What is the definition of $\delta$-separated? If my guess is correct, then it implies discrete.

Comment: $A$ $\delta$-separated if $d(a,a')\geq \delta \forall a\neq a'\in A$

Comment: So then $A$ is closed and discrete since for every $x\in\mathbb R$ the $\delta/2$ ball centered at $x$ meets at most one point of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

If $\delta >0$ the any $\delta$ separated set is discrete because it has no limit points.

Comment: It is also discrete as a sub$space$ because in the sub-space topology any  non-empty open ball of radius $\delta/2$ contains exactly one point...............+1